# Why is java "highest" superclass called "Object"?

Tags: java, oop, object

I have a strange (and maybe silly) question: I was wondering.... why is java "Object" class called "Object", not "Class"?

For example, for ArrayList whe have the following hierarchy

```
Object ->
Collection ->
List ->
ArrayList
```

Ok: ArrayList is a List... List is a Collection... but a Collection (the class of all collections) is not an Object... it is a class!

Comment: The default superclass of all objects is Object. If you declare a class without a superclass, its superclass is Object.

Comment: You can't really have a superclass of an object, can you? Only classes should have superclasses.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Think about what the object itself is. An `ArrayList` is a list, yes? It's also an object. It's *not* a class of object. The class name describes what *instances* of that class represent.

*A collection* isn't a class of collections - it's *a collection* (and it's an object).

Comment: Also Neither List nor Collection are Classes they are interfaces.

Comment: This phrase: "The class name describes what instances of that class represent." answered my question! thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Well, you use `Object` to declare an *instance* of a (not better specified) Object, same as you use `Collection` to declare an *instance* of a Collection.

You can declare an object of type Class too, with `java.lang.Class<T>`, where an *instance* of it represents the Class of the Object

Answer (score 1):

`Collection` is an interface (effectively a special type of class).

**A** `Collection` is an object.

Comment: My question is: why not to use Class instead of objec: An instance of a Collection is an Object... but the Class (or the interface) Collection is not an Object... it is a "Class"

Comment: @Salles Object is the class of all objects; Collections is the class of all collections.

Answer (score 1):

Your assumption is incorrect. The correct hiearchy for ArrayList is:
ArrayList -->
AbstractList -->
AbstractCollection --> 
Object

So even ArrayList has Object as the first thing in its hierarchy.