# In java why is Object class named so even after being a class?

Tags: java, class, oop, object

We know that all classes have at least one class as it's superclass i.e. Object class. My question is if Object is a class and we already have a class named Class, but if Object itself is a class why not name it Class and name the original Class class as something else?

What was the reason for choosing this name as it is not an actual object but a class and it is really important to get your nomenclature in place for any programming language, is it to satisfy some kind of Object Oriented relationship such as an **Object HAS A Class** ?

Comment: "all classes have at least one class" ... what on earth are you talking about?

Comment: my bad let me edit

Comment: because Class is not a baseClass, it's a type. what is not an actual Object?

Comment: Classes are named for what the instances of that class represent. In this case any object. By your logic every class should have "class" in its name for example a `class Dog` would by your logic have to be named `class DogClass` because it itself is just a class and not an instance that represents a Dog.

Comment: Once you instantiate it, it becomes an object of type Object. Also, there is actually a class named Class, which represents the class of an object. You can actually get objects of type Class.

Comment: @OHGODSPIDERS sorry that's not what I meant, I am just asking that if you've a parent class it's name would some how suggest some relationship to it's child class. What kind of re;ationship is represented by naming it Object class?

Comment: @TGW all child instances of it's child classes are Objects. how is that not a good choice?

Comment: Because every instance of that Object class or one of its subclasses is an object. Not sure whats unclear about that.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why is java "highest" superclass called "Object"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9707130/why-is-java-highest-superclass-called-object)

Comment: That's what my last statement asks which means Object HAS A CLASS it could be any class including a Dog,Square,Rectangle?

Comment: @TGW no. Even though each Dog instance is an Object, not each Object is a Dog. if you would put Dog.class as the class for Object.java, even a String would be a Dog ...

Comment: I don't get what you are trying to say here. Maybe you are unfamiliar with the fact that the term "object" isn't something that java invented. It's a term whose meaning existed long before.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instances of the `Class` class represent the **meta information** of classes. For example the fields declared in a class or the available methods. This information can for example be used with the reflection API to dynamically access functionality during runtime.

`Object` defines **common functionality** shared by all instances of each and every class (including instances of `Class`). This functionality is extended/modified by deriving from `Object` or any other class.

Regrading the naming from an OO perspective it seems quite natural to name the root class of everything `Object`. Naturally one would say trees are objects, and cars are objects. But not trees are classes.

Comment: That's what I wanted to know your last paragraph simplifies the explanation.

Comment: "not trees are classes" ? if you create a Car.java and a Tree.java, Tree is a class

Comment: Of course `Tree` is a class, which defines the properties of instances of `Tree`. But instances of `Tree` are `Object`s and not `Class`es.

Answer (score 3):

Physically, classes represent Java class definitions.
All compiled Java classes are indeed defined in classes (`.class` files).
So `Class` would be a very ambiguous name to also represent the `Object` class.

To answer to you comment : so why `Object` as class name ?
[Object-oriented programming (OOP)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object-oriented_programming) refers to a programming **object** paradigm where we manipulate **objects**.

In the class-based programming (the OOP style which Java belongs), class names should represent concepts/things.
So, `Object` appears as very suitable to name the base class as it refers to a really broad concept/thing.

Comment: Yes but still that does not seem to be a reason as to why I would name it Object?

Comment: Hmmm. Don't you find meaningful to name the base class of every object : Object ?

Comment: @TGW why you would name it? you don't have to name it, the designers of Java did that. but, again: what exactly is confusing you?

Comment: It's not confusing it's just that I want to know the reason behind such a name I've already accepted that they follow one of the best naming conventions just want to understand in Layman's terms that what was their intention behind naming a class Object

Comment: @TGW the term 'object' existed long before Java was invented. They re-used terminology as was already in place, so as developers would know what they were talking about.

Comment: @Stultuske can we put it this way that everything that we define is an object thus satisfying an Is A relationship, hence naming it object so that any class you define eventually after instantiation is always interpreted as an object? Maybe something what dpr mentioned in last paragraph of his answer?

Comment: @TGW seeing as dpr claims a Tree wouldn't be a class, I wouldn't go there. Everything in Java is an Object, except for the primitive types. Even utility classes, with nothing next to static methods can be instantiated.

Comment: So from what you mentioned what kind of Object Oriented relationship would this name satisfy? I am not saying that it should I just wanted to know if it does? Is-A or Has-A or Part-Of